# Bash Logical operation into variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

Easy one for you.
Can we do something like this in Bash, without using IF statements?

```
a=0
b=0
c=1

result= [ a || b || c ] # result of binary operation should be 1
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the bitwise operators present in the arithmetic expression:

```
result=$((a|b|c))
```

(and similarly `&` for AND and `^` for XOR).

The logical operators work in arithmetic expressions, too:

```
result=$((a||b||c))
```

(and similarly `&&`).

The assignment can be part of the expression itself (spaces are permitted around the `=` in this case):

```
(( result = a || b || c ))
```

If you use `true` and `false` instead, you don't need any brackets at all:

```
a=false
b=false
c=true
a || b || c
result=$?
```

The problem is that in this case, 0 means true.

In square brackets, only unset or empty value is false by itself. So, you can use

```
a=
b=
c=1
[[ $a || $b || $c ]]
result=$?
```

Again, zero corresponds to true, but you can fix that by changing it to

```
! [[ $a || $b || $c ]]
```

Comment: You will be my accepted answer. Can you please provide any other ways? Maybe with the square brackets?

Comment: are square brackets possible?

Answer (score -2):

My variant how to define complex expression first and resolve later:

```
TIME=10#$(date +%H%M)
DAY=$(date +%a)

case $DAY in
  Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri)
    a=$(( 10#0110 < $TIME && $TIME < 10#0530 || 1630 < $TIME && $TIME < 1910 ))
    ;;
  Sat|Sun)
    a=$(( 10#0150 < $TIME && $TIME < 10#0650 || 1610 < $TIME && $TIME < 1910 ))
    ;;
  *)
    a=0
    ;;
esac
if [[ $a == 1 ]]
then
  echo "Cheap electricity"
else
  echo "Expensive electricity"
fi
```

Note `10#` prefix prevents bash to interpret zero leading number in octal arithmetic and forces to use decimal arithmetic.

Comment: Note that `0530` (for example) in an arithmetic context (inside `$((...))`) is an octal constant equal to the decimal value 344.  Try running your code, and you will see that you get an error if the current time is before 10:00 and contains the digit `9`.  This is due to `9` not being a valid digit in octal numbers.

Comment: @Kusalananda many thanks, you are absolutely right. Yesterday evening I wrote the code and wandering in the morning why it did not work. `10#` prefix is needed to force decimal arithmetic.

Comment: There will still be an issue with the time stored in `$TIME`.